# Microsoft Graph Api not filtering calendar events correctly

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-graph-api

I am trying to use filter operator to find the events between specific date and time. Now, it only searches single events, any occurrence of recurring events are being excluded.

Following i tried in Graph explorer

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2022-09-20T00:00:00Z' and end/dateTime le '2022-09-20T23:59:00Z'
```

it was working all ok few months back and was returning single occurrences of recurring events as well , but now its behaving differently. Can anyone suggest if i am doing something wrong or something changed.

Thanks
Nitin

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to describe the problem you're having or question you're asking. *Issue with* is a useless phrase. Every question asked here about the Graph API is because someone's having an *issue*. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to convey meaning to a future site user who is skimming a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title is useless in that regard. Your *its behaving differently* is also a meaningless phrase - you've not described how you expect it to work and what is happening instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be using a CalendarView to expand recurring appointments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-calendarview?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . The API shouldn't expand recurring appointment if you make a normal query like your example. This is important if you have any application that is syncing the real exchange store items vs the expanded virtual ones. If it was previously doing that then it was most likely a bug that was fixed.